# heroku - buildpacks generate slug size too heavy

Tags: node.js, heroku, buildpack

I've started to create a very simple nodeJS server,

For now, the server do **nothing**.

I'm trying to install many buildpacks on my **heroku server** (The purpose of my server is a document convertor)

so this is my `.buildpacks` :

```
https://github.com/rishihahs/heroku-buildpack-libreoffice.git
https://github.com/elbongurk/heroku-buildpack-ghostscript.git
https://github.com/GetJobber/heroku-buildpack-poppler.git
https://github.com/ello/heroku-buildpack-imagemagick
```

So when I try to **git push heroku**, everything is installed, but when it's the `compression` times, I got this message :

```
remote:  !     Compiled slug size: 321.1M is too large (max is 300M).
```

How can I avoid that ?

(nb: there is nothing I can't send from my code, so no slugfile)

Answer (score 0):

Here are some things to try.

1. Get the `heroku repo` [plugin](https://github.com/heroku/heroku-repo) and use `heroku repo:purge_cache -a <app name>`.  Sometimes that helps.
2. Carefully go through the buildpacks and check for redundancy.  For example, sometimes different buildpacks will both install the same package, which takes up extra space.
3. Sometimes static files are the problem.  You could try a [CDN](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/using-amazon-cloudfront-cdn).
4. Contact Heroku directly.
5. Go to a different platform, or perhaps use an IaaS platform.